# d3 - Scaling @ Normalized Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to code a reusable chart in d3 - a "normalized" stacked bar chart. The data are scaled from 0% -100% on the Y-axis - see: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886394 
I have understood that I need to calculate the inverse value of the data, to scale from 0 (Y: lowest value 0%) to 1 (Y: highest value 100%).

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);  // no data domain

dataSet = dataSet.map(function (d) {
            return d.map(function (p, i) {
                return { x: i, y: (1 / (p.Value / 100))};
            });
        });
```

However, my scaling is not working correctly

- please have a look @ http://jsfiddle.net/dB96T/1/

thx!!

Comment: Have you had a look at Mike Bostock's example, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886394 ?

Comment: yes, that was my first point.

Comment: I created a quick [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QVHBbS3gh3l8jLovIXzI?p=preview) for you that takes your data and applies it to Mike's example you linked. This should give you some guidance on where your current data manipulation is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry for missing the obvious link in your post. [Here's a fiddle that seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/dB96T/4/), but the approach used by @FernOfTheAndes might be better. I followed Mike B's example and didn't used the stack layout.

Comment: @JamesTrimble You are good James...I did the same thing and used the example given by the OP, which does not use the stack layout. In any case, this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250053/use-d3-js-layout-stack-to-make-a-normalized-stacked-bar-chart) is instructive.